# How to filter values in an array column in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column of ArrayType in Pyspark. I want to filter only the values in the Array for every Row (I don't want to filter out actual rows!) without using UDF.

For instance given this dataset with column A of ArrayType:

```
|     A      |
______________
|[-2, 1, 7]  |
|[1]         |
|[-4, -1, -3]|
```

And I would like to have only positive values the output would be:

```
|     A      |
______________
|[1, 7]      |
|[1]         |
|[]          |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Spark 2.4 and above,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("A", expr("filter(A, x -> x > 0)")).show()
```